# Adding new data to DB when using 2 tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to mvc and mvc 3 , I have a db that contain a company table (string id =as the company name )

And a table tourism that contain same info I would like to be able to add data  to the tourism table , while selecting a company from the list (that came from the company table)
(The two tables had a dependency vie company_id (and the same name in both))
How can I do it?
Leo_a

Answer (score 1):

1. create a transaction
2. insert into the dependent table
3. inserrt into the main table
4. commit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  You want to select from one table and update the other with the data you selected from the first?  Do you have any sample code you can post?

Comment: hi, no, i have the comapny lets say USA airline, (this is in company table)and they have a flyet rout to London and paris and Berlin (this is table tourism) i would like to update the scound table using the company's in the first table I hope this is more clear